# Question About Maximal Smooth Atlas

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

**Definition of Maximal Smooth Atlas:** In the text GTM $218$ by John Lee, the author defines a smooth altas $\mathcal{A}$ to be a maximal smooth atlas if any chart that is smoothly compatible with every chart in $\mathcal{A}$ is already in $\mathcal{A}$.

The author makes a comment that, if a topological manifold $M$ can be covered by a single chart, the smooth compatibility condition is trivially satisfied, so any such chart automatically determines a smooth structure on $M$, which means a maximal smooth altas on $M$.

Now let's consider an example.

Take the manifold $M=\mathbb{R}^n.$ Let $\mathcal{A}_1=\{ (\mathbb{R}^n,Id_{\mathbb{R}^n})\}$ and  $\mathcal{A}_2=\{ (B_1(x),Id_{B_1(x)}):x\in \mathbb{R}^n\}$.

By author's comment, $\mathcal{A}_1$ should be a maximal smooth atlas on $M$. But it is obvious that every chart in $\mathcal{A}_2$ is compatible with the only chart in $\mathcal{A}_1$. And by the definition of maximal smooth atlas, $\mathcal{A}_1$ is not maximal because at least it doesn't contain those charts in $\mathcal{A}_2$.

I'm quite confused now. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, I didn't say that $\mathscr A_1$ is a maximal smooth atlas, I said it *determines* a maximal smooth atlas. This is a reference to Proposition 1.17(a), which says "every smooth atlas $\mathscr A$ for $M$ is contained in a unique maximal smooth atlas,
called the ***smooth structure determined by ${\mathscr A}$***."

Comment: I was just about to quote that relevant portion of your (excellent!) book but now I don't have to :)

Comment: Oh yeah, the word you use is $\textit{determine}$. Sorry maybe I read too fast and carelessly... Thanks!